# Sum integers using template recursion going upwards possible?

Tags: c++, recursive-templates

Using recursive templates, I would like to calculate the sum of the first `n` integers going from 0 to `n`. I.e. `SumUp<10>::n` would be 55. I wonder because I'm used to recursion going downwards (ie. from `n` to 0). Is it possible to go from 0 to n? Here's my attempt:

```
template<int n> struct SumUp {
    static constexpr int n = n;
};

template<> struct SumUp<0> {
    static constexpr int n = 0 + SumUp<n + 1>::n;  // <- Problem
};
```

The problem is, that in the second template, `n` is not known and therefore doesn't compile.

Comment: How would a simple `SumUp<0>` work?  You are still unconditionally calling `SumUp<n + 1>`

Comment: Is it possible, yes -- but like any recursive definition, you need to know the stopping point. If you want to count up, then you need to know what the end-point is (e.g. you need to pass `N` along with the start condition, and stop when `Current == N`)

Comment: Consider loop down: Sum<0> is 0, Sum<N> is N + Sum<N-1>.

Comment: Why not `std::integer_sequence` combined with a fold expression?

Answer (score 1):

"Downwards" recursion counts upwards already.

When you do, for instance

```
int sum(int N)
{
    if (N == 0) return 0;
    return sum(N-1) + N
}
```

You actually compute sum(0) first.
Then sum(1) = sum(0) + 1
Then sum(2) = sum(1) + 2
Then sum(3) = sum(2) + 3

I wrote it as a regular function, but same holds regardless of language, be it runtime c++, templates, or visual basic.

Now if you want to reverse this and count downwards, you need to keep track of the target.

```
template<int N, int i = 0> struct SumUp {
    static constexpr int n = i + SumUp<N, i+1>::n;
};

template<int N> struct SumUp<N, N> {
    static constexpr int n = N;
};

static_assert(SumUp<1>::n == 1);
static_assert(SumUp<2>::n == 3);
static_assert(SumUp<3>::n == 6);
static_assert(SumUp<4>::n == 10);
```

- First part defines SumUp<n, i> as the sum of integers in range [i..n].
- Second part defines a stop condition when n == i.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If it makes it clearer, you can do `SumUp<N, N+1> { static constexpr int n = 0; }`. You would break the recursion one step later with the same result. Except I am not sure N, N+1 would work as a specialization. Perhaps with some integral_constat magic.

Comment: Oh right, it's late here my brain doesn't parse humour well so far in the night :) As for the point, I don't know, OP wanted to do it reversed, I guess as some training exercise or pure curiosity.

Comment: I think this is a simple solution that does what the OP requires. I did post an answer based on integer sequence, but I now think this is simpler.